# A question about a situation in category Div

Tags: category-theory

I read the article of wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism.

If you read in section "Examples", you will see:

"To go from that implication to the fact that q is a monomorphism, assume that q ∘ f = q ∘ g for some morphisms f, g : G → Q, where G is some divisible group. Then **q ∘ (f − g) = 0**, where (f − g) : x ↦ f(x) − g(x). (Since (f − g)(0) = 0, and (f − g)(x + y) = (f − g)(x) + (f − g)(y), it follows that (f − g) ∈ Hom(G, Q)). From the implication just proved, q ∘ (f − g) = 0 ⇒ f − g = 0 ⇔ ∀ x ∈ G, f(x) = g(x) ⇔ f = g. Hence q is a monomorphism, as claimed."

why this situation "q ∘ (f − g) = 0" is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The category $\mathbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups is enriched in itself: this means that for any two abelian groups $A$ and $B$, the collection of group homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$ forms an abelian group.

Hence, if $f,g:B\to C$ are two parallel arrows, and $h:A\to B$ is a third arrow, then $f\circ h=g\circ h$ if and only if $(f-g)h=0$; you can simply view the group homomorphisms as abelian group elements as in ordinary group theory.

Comment: i can't understand what is $0$ of $(f−g)h=0$

Comment: Doesn't every abelian group have a neutral element? Clearly we write the abelian group of the homomorphisms additively.

Comment: yes undersstand.